# Loading a saved RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was just playing around this tutorial from TensorFlow.

A complete step by step guide is provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent).

And the source code is given [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb).

Now I want to do something more. I want to save the trained RNN and load it in another python script, so that I can give input to the RNN and it will generate the next probable word.

To save the model I ran the command:

```
cd models/tutorials/rnn/ptb
python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=/tmp/simple-examples/data/ --model=small --save_path=~/Desktop/SavedRNN/
```

Then I got a checkpoint file with these entries:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "/home/piyush/Documents/college courses/year 3/sem 6/Information Retrieval/project2/-30199"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/home/piyush/Documents/college courses/year 3/sem 6/Information Retrieval/project2/model.ckpt-24745"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/home/piyush/Documents/college courses/year 3/sem 6/Information Retrieval/project2/model.ckpt-26220"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/home/piyush/Documents/college courses/year 3/sem 6/Information Retrieval/project2/model.ckpt-27762"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/home/piyush/Documents/college courses/year 3/sem 6/Information Retrieval/project2/model.ckpt-29237"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "/home/piyush/Documents/college courses/year 3/sem 6/Information Retrieval/project2/-30199"
```

And I got 9 files of 3 types

```
models.ckpt.<some-number>.data-00000-of-00001
models.ckpt.<some-number>.meta
models.ckpt.<some-number>.index
```

Now I am unable to find any documentation to load this model in tensorflow. All the examples I came across were just using the `tf.saver` with only one checkpoint.

I am guessing, it has something to do with `supervisor`. But I am not sure.

Now the missing steps I want to perform is:

1. Load the saved model in TensorFlow (python)
2. Run the model with my own input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loa the model you pass the checkpoint path up to `<some_number>` to the Saver when loading the model (this should be after building the graph, reusing the code in the example provided).

Comment: After searching more I found out that we can use meta file to load the graph. Also I want to know how to give my own seed and get the result of the RNN?